# C Bitwise Circle Shifting - Unexpected Results

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

I'm currently working through the K&R C book exercises and am on exercise 8 of chapter 2. The challenge is to write a function 'rotright' that rotates (or circle shifts) the bits of unsigned integer x by n bits. I believe I've come up with a solution, but it's not returning what I would expect. Given the number `213`, which is `11010101` in binary, rotating `2` bits to the right would yield `01110101`, which is `117`. However, my program upon being given `x=213` and `n=2` returns `53`. I've tried writing out the process of what's happening to the integer in binary form in comments and can't find a problem. Any help would be appreciated.

```
#include <stdio.h>

unsigned rotright(unsigned x, int n)
{
    /* Example with x = 11010101 (213 in decimal), n = 2
        First iteration:
            x = (01101010) | ~(11111111 >> 1) = 11101010
        Second iteration:
            x = (01110101) | ~(11111111 >> 0) = 01110101
        Returns 01110101

    right shifts only if last bit of x == 1, then sets first bit of right shifted x to 1
    if last bit of x == 0, x is right shifted by 1 and then unchanged.

    (01101010) | ~(11111111 >> (11010101 & 00000001))
    = 01101010 | ~(11111111 >> 00000001)
    = 01101010 | 10000000 = 11101010

    (11101010) | ~(11111111 >> (11101010 & 00000001))
    = 01110101 | ~(11111111 >> 0)
    = 01110101 | 00000000 = 01110101
    */
    for (; n > 0; n--)
        x = (x >> 1) | ~(~0 >> (x & 1));
    return x;
}

int main()
{
    printf("%d\n", rotright(213, 2));
    return 0; 
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> x = (x >> 1) | ~(~0 >> (x & 1));

you get 53 because this is (213 >> 2)

`~(~0 >> (x & 1))` is always 0, because ~0 is -1, and (-1 >> n) is again -1 in your case, and finally ~(-1) is 0

---

You want that :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>

unsigned rotright(unsigned x, int n)
{
   unsigned mask = (1u << (CHAR_BIT * sizeof(int) - 1));

  for (; n > 0; n--) {
    x = (x / 2) | ((x & 1) ? mask : 0);
  }
  return x;
}

int main()
{
    printf("%d\n", rotright(213, 2));
    return 0; 
}
```

On 32bits the result is 1073741877 being 1000000000000000000000000110101, not 117 whose supposes you work on 8 bits

Comment: ... and `~0` is `-1` because the type of the constant `0` is `int`.  Switching to `unsigned int` is as simple as using `0u`, instead.  Also, the effect of right-shifting a negative value is not necessarily an arithmetic shift, such as, I agree, the OP seems to observe.  It is implementation-defined, so it might instead be the logical shift the OP expected, or even something else.

Comment: @JohnBollinger this is why I said _in your case_

Comment: Thanks for the responses. I had forgotten right shifting signed values was unique. For this reason would you suggest I avoid doing so in the future, so I know what to expect?

Comment: `((x&1) ? mask : 0)` can be replaced by `(~((x&1)-1) & mask)` to avoid the branch.

Comment: @muke divide by 2 rather than >> 1 to be sure of the result

Comment: @muke, as a general rule, yes, it is best to avoid using signed data types in bitwise operations.

Comment: There are two problems with using division instead of shifting, @bruno: (1) when dividend is -1 -- as in fact is the OP's case -- the division yields 0, not -1; and (2) the division by 2 otherwise reliably produces the same results as an arithmetic right shift, but the OP wants a *logical* shift.

Comment: @JohnBollinger we are in the case of an _unsigned int_ above, and previously we do not wanted a rotate but a shift, so -1/2 = 0 is ok

Comment: I am speaking about the general case, @bruno, lest some future reader get the idea that dividing a signed integer by two is exactly equivalent to right-shifting it by one.  I acknowledge that the differences are moot for the OP's specific problem.